# Resolve local host without any DNS server?

Tags: linux, dns, ipv6, dig, nslookup

Is there any way to resolve local host without any DNS server?

Below is my config

```
# ifconfig
eth4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:9C:4D:2F
          inet6 addr: 2004:c0a8:5b01:1:250:56ff:fe9c:4d2f/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe9c:4d2f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:196832 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12558 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:16362576 (15.6 MiB)  TX bytes:2467903 (2.3 MiB)
```

I have added name in `/etc/hosts` file also

```
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
2004:c0a8:5b01:1:250:56ff:fe9c:4d2f  saravana69rhel83 
2004:c0a8:5b01:1:250:56ff:fe9c:4d2f         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
::1  saravana69rhel83
```

When I try to do a DNS lookup, it is not resolving at all:

```
# dig saravana69rhel83  AAAA

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4 <<>> saravana69rhel83  AAAA
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

**EDIT**

```
[root@saravana69rhel83 ~]# ping saravana69rhel83 
ping: unknown host saravana69rhel83 
[root@saravana69rhel83 ~]# ping6 saravana69rhel83 
PING saravana69rhel83 (saravana69rhel83 ) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from saravana69rhel83 : icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
^C
--- saravana69rhel83  ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 855ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.030/0.030/0.030/0.000 ms
[root@saravana69rhel83 ~]#


[root@saravana69rhel83 ~]# nslookup -query=AAAA saravana69rhel83 
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

[root@saravana69rhel83 ~]#
```

Comment: As a side note you speak about `nslookup` but then use `dig`. You do well, you should prefer `dig`. And based on your directory where you are, DNSmasq can be a local resolver for your needs.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to resolve it with some local resolver. Could not make it!!

Answer (score 3):

You're using `/etc/hosts` correctly but `nslookup` ignores the hosts file. It is doing a DNS lookup not a lookup of how the hostname resolves in your configured environment. Try `ping`ing the hostname instead as that will include hosts file.

See [why is my /etc/hosts file not queried when...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627906/why-is-my-etc-hosts-file-not-queried-when-nslookup-tries-to-resolve-an-address)